# How to model non-linear, linear and crossed random effects in one model

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, nonlinear

I have a model with fixed and crossed random effects like this:

glmer(response~1+var1+var2+var3+var3^2+(1|var4)+(1|var5)+(1|var6), family="poisson")

Now, I decided that variable3 is best modelled not by quadratic relation, but by michaelis-menten relation, so (alpha*var3)/(beta+var3). How do I incorporate it in my model, so that I am still able to retain my variables var1 and var2 and my crossed random effects and I also want to be able to do model selection.